# Facebook integration in Android APK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have problem like how to send Game Feed from android aplication.
How to send somethink like that:
 1. Frends of user can see it in Game Activity, in Last Activity
 2. How to send Message from APK to user

I had read many stackoverflow questions but no one give me the answear how to do it from APK
Everywhere is from www server on from apk in facebook where they had canvas.
I got my apk on android and u can login with facebook to it.
I can send a post on Your wall but theres no information in Game feed, game activity, in last activity. There's no notifications at all.

Anyone know hot to do it, with Graph or Dialog ?
(I want it to do with out confirming  of user to send or post)

Comment: **how to do it from APK**, can't understand this sentence.

Comment: from application installed on mobile devices.

Comment: There is library available made from facebook graph API, you can use it. It will display dialog webview.